# How can I get the same week day from previous year in Tableau using a calculated field? For example the week day of 06/02/2020

Tags: sql, database, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I need to add the week day from previous year on the 3rd column.

Form example 06/02/2021 was on a Wednesday. I need the week day of 06/02/2021.

Thanks

Comment: What is your underlying database?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday,DATEADD(YEAR, -1, '06-02-2021'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tableau is notoriously difficult to figure out work days. As some have suggested, it may be easier to use the underlying database to calculate this.  However, if you need to do this in Tableau it can be accomplished like this:

```
DATEADD(
 "day"
 ,CASE LEFT(LOWER(DATENAME("weekday",[DateFieldUsed])), 3)
      WHEN 'fri' THEN 3
      WHEN 'sat' THEN 2
      ELSE 1
     END
 ,[DateFieldUsed]
)
```

Basically, if it is Friday you need to add 3 days to the date, Saturday you need to add, and in any other situations just add 1 date.  (please test, not doing this in Tableau so the numbers may be off).

I may have misunderstood the question, the example isn't exactly what you're asking.  If your current value is 6/2/2021, and you are trying to find the week day of 6/2/2020, I would do this:

```
DATENAME("weekday", DATEADD(year, -1, [DateFieldUsed])
```